# How to tell which Bluetooth adapter a device is connected to via the command line?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

I can't figure out how to do this via the CLI.

If we're talking GUI, then [Blueman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blueman) can do this for me but I need a CLI solution for a script I'm making.

And between `bluetoothctl` and `pacmd` (PulseAudio), neither will actually tell me exactly which of my two Bluetooth adapters my headphones are connected to — only whether or not it's connected at all.

Comment: Have you tried, `hciconfig scan`? Or perhaps `hciconfig con`? More info at the man page for [`hciconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hcitool).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for reminding me--just read through all my options on hciconfig as well as hcitool, but no dice. hcitool info <MAC> seems to have literally everything else I might need to know, but not which adapter it's connected to.

Fortunately, I figured a way around needing to do this in my script. Although it would be troubling if there was legitimately no way to do this in userspace.